# Calculate properties using items in List with conditions

Tags: c#

I have a list object that has several properties that I want to use for calculations for an model properties.

something like:

```
List<Cars>
```

that has properties for Wheels/Windows/HasRoof/FuelType, etc.

I have a model for "Parts" (class example below) that I want to fill but I have a few rules to apply, I'm going to pseudoCode what I think I should do, but I'm not sure if this is the approach for this:

```
  public class Parts
    {
        public int AmountOfWheels { get; set; }
        public int AmountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas { get; set; }
        public AmountOfWindowsForCarsWithRoof Type { get; set; }
    }

public Parts Parts { get; set; }
```

this is what I want to fill:

```
    foreach (var item in Cars)
    {
        Parts.AmountOfWheels =+ item.Wheels;
        Parts.AmountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas   // <-- This is what I don't know
        Parts.AmountOfWindowsForCarsWithRoof // <-- This is what I don't know
    }
```

Then later I want to show the user this Parts object in a webApp, but I'm not sure how to populate this object.

The part I'm not sure if it's ok to do the calculations like this or shall I do something in the object model with properties

Comment: You haven't shown us what `Car` looks like but I'm guessing you want something like `if (item.FuelType == FuelType.Gas) Parts.AmountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas += item.Wheels;`? Similarly, for the second one, you'd check for `item.HasRoof`, for example.

Comment: yes, something like that, I should do it with if for the conditions? ok, makes sense. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you're getting at, but tell me if I miss the mark!

For most UIs including web apps, the UI box that is displaying something like `AmountOfWheels` is *bound* to changes of that property using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. If your `Parts` class implements that interface, then when this line in your code executes:

```
Parts.AmountOfWheels =+ item.Wheels;
```

that will change the value of `AmountOfWheels` property and *that* will fire a property changed event. The calculation in turn will set the other properties (like `AmountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas`). That fires its own changed event and the UI just picks up on that property change and shows the value.

```
// A class that notifies when its properties change
class Part : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// The private 'backing store' of the variable which is a Field
    /// </summary>
    private int _amountOfWheels = 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// The public property
    /// </summary>
    public int AmountOfWheels
    {
        get => _amountOfWheels;
        set
        {
            if (_amountOfWheels != value)
            {
                _amountOfWheels = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    int _amountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas = -1;
    public int AmountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas 
    {
        get => _amountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas;
        set
        {
            if (_amountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas != value)
            {
                _amountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case nameof(AmountOfWheels):
                onAmountOfWheelsChanged();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void onAmountOfWheelsChanged()
    {
        // Perform some calculation based on AmountOfWheels.
        AmountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas = TestDataGenerator.Next(0,10);
    }
    private Random TestDataGenerator = new Random();
}
```

Test driver for it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var part = new Part();
        part.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case nameof(Part.AmountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas):
                    Console.WriteLine($"Amount of Wheels {part.AmountOfWheels} = (Rando test data){part.AmountOfWheelsForFuelTypeGas}");
                    break;
            }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            part.AmountOfWheels = i;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]